# How to order posts in wp_query by a meta_value of the corresponding author

Tags: wp-query, order

Is it possible to order posts retrieved via `WP_Query` according to a meta value of the corresponding **post author**?

Use case: I have premium subscribers and basic subscribers. I want the posts of the premium subscribers to appear before the posts of the basic subscribers in a search result page.

One way to solve this, would be to add a `meta_key` to the **post**, indicating the author's subscriber status, but I would have to update all posts of a user everytime this user's status changes.

Is there a way to make this work by referring to the user meta values directly?

```
$args = array(
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'listing',
            'meta_key' => '???', // how can I refer to the meta_key of the author of a post ?
            'orderby' => '???',
            'order' => 'DESC'
        );

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: How is `premium subscribers` and `basic subscribers` saved in the db? These must be relationship here to the author. There should be some value saved in the db that will distinguish a `premium subscriber` from a `basic subscribers`

Comment: yes, in `wp_usermeta` there is the `account` (meta_key) with the `meta_values` `1` for basic and `2` for premium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you an idea and I believe this should help you forward.

This query first uses [`WP_User_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) to fetch all users that are authors registered as premium subscribers and basic subscribers. These users are ordered by `meta_value` so that premium subscribers are shown first.

A `foreach` loop return each users' own ID which can be returned into [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to display posts for each user in order of the `meta_value`

Here is the complete code. Modify it as needed

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'who' => 'authors',
    'meta_key' => 'account',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'account',
            'value' => array(1, 2),
        )
    )
);

// The WP_User_Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// User Loop
if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
        $user->ID;

        $the_query = new WP_Query( 'author=' . $user->ID . '&post_status=publish&post_type=listing' );
        echo '<p>' . $user->display_name . '</p>';
        // The Loop
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            echo '<ul>';
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                $the_query->the_post();
                echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        } 
        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is what you're looking for:

You will need to specify for each post, it's "subscriber_status" (Which will need to be a custom meta field). You will also need to assign a custom meta field to each author for their respective "subscriber_status".

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

// This represents the custom meta field associated with the user data
$subscriber_status = get_the_author_meta('subscriber_status', $current_user->ID);

// This will query against the custom meta field associated with the post data
$query = new WP_Query([
    'post_type'   => 'listing',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key'    => 'subscriber_status',
    'meta_value'  => $subscriber_status,
    'order_by'    => 'meta_value',
    'order'       => 'DESC',
]);
```

Hopefully that helps you out.

[More on `wp_get_current_user()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user)

[More on `get_the_author_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta)

[More on `WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)