# Sort users by meta_value_num

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I'm having problems using `WP_User_Query` to sort users by a meta value number, I would of thought this would be simple by it just displays results as descending alphabetically.

```
 <?php
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key ' => 'epicredvote',
    'order' => 'DESC',
);

// The Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// User Loop
if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
        echo '<p>' . $user->display_name . '</p>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No users found.';
}
?>
```

I can get the meta value for each author easily enough but I can't get users to sort by the same meta value.

EDIT for birgire's answer.

This still outputs 'no users found'.

In functions.php

```
function wpse_149342_pre_user_query( $query )
{
    remove_action( current_action(), __FUNCTION__ );

    $query->query_orderby = str_replace( 
        'meta_value', 
        'meta_value+0', 
        $query->query_orderby 
    );
}
```

Loop:-

```
   <?php
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'epicredvote',
    'orderby'  => 'meta_value',
    'order'    => 'DESC',
);
add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'wpse_149342_pre_user_query' );

// The Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// User Loop
if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
        echo '<p>' . $user->display_name . '</p>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No users found.';
}
?>
```

Version of wordpress is 3.9.1.

I took a look at pieter's answer and I can't get my head around it.

Let me explain a little what the meta_key is in this case.

epicredvote is a numeric value, each post has a voting system, John makes 2 posts, each gets 10 votes, John then has 20 votes in total for both of his posts.

On author.php I use this to extract the total number of votes that user has received for all of their posts.

```
function author_rating_total() {
   $user_id = get_the_author_meta( 'ID' );
   $query = array (
       'author' => $user_id,
       'suppress_filters' => 'true', //lets skip some unnessecery sql queries
       'posts_per_page' => -1
   );
   $queryObject = new WP_Query($query); while($queryObject->have_posts()) : $queryObject->the_post();

   $post_ratings_data = get_post_custom(get_the_id());
   $post_ratings_score = intval($post_ratings_data['epicredvote'][0]);

   $ratings_array[] = $post_ratings_score;

   endwhile; 

   $ratings_sum = 0;
   if (is_array($ratings_array)){
    $ratings_sum = array_sum($ratings_array);
    }

   echo $ratings_sum;   

   wp_reset_query();
}
```

I can then do  `echo author_rating_total();` to display the aggregated number of votes that user has received for all of their posts.

Would of thought it'd be easy to use WP_user_query to extract the same meta value then rank authors accordingly over a given date range, apparently not so much!

There's got to be a way though!

Comment: Which wordpress version are you using

Comment: 3.9, the latest version

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/147427/31545) I did, might shed some light on your problem

Comment: I edited my original question, hope that's clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in `functions.php`. 
Use `orderby` with `meta_value_num` and define `meta_key` in argument array.

```
add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'wps_pre_user_query' );

function wps_pre_user_query( &$query ) {
    global $wpdb;

    if ( isset( $query->query_vars['orderby'] ) && 'meta_value_num' == $query->query_vars['orderby'] )
        $query->query_orderby = str_replace( 'user_login', "$wpdb->usermeta.meta_value+0", $query->query_orderby );
}
```

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks. Hopefully 'meta_value_num' will get encapsulated into WP_User_Query in core soon.

Comment: Happy to help you :), However I have submitted a [ticket here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/31220), hope it will be added.

Answer (score 0):

Although `meta_value_num` would be valid for `WP_Query`, I don't see any mention of it in the docs for `WP_User_Query`.

Instead, try

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value'
```

Comment: 'no users found'. Wonder if it's possible to get users with wp_query

Comment: Long shot: you're not on a version older than 3.7 are you?

Comment: Latest version of wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to modify the *orderby* part through the [`pre_user_query`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.9.1/src/wp-includes/user.php#L693) hook:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'epicredvote',
    'orderby'  => 'meta_value',
    'order'    => 'DESC',
);

add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'wpse_149342_pre_user_query' );

$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```

where:

```
/**
 * Change 'meta_value' to 'meta_value_num'
 *
 * @param WP_User_Query $query
 * @return void
 */

function wpse_149342_pre_user_query( $query )
{
    remove_action( current_action(), __FUNCTION__ );

    $query->query_orderby = str_replace( 
        'meta_value', 
        'meta_value+0', 
        $query->query_orderby 
    );
}
```

Here's an example of the modified SQL query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_users.* 
    FROM wp_users 
    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON (wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id) 
    WHERE 1=1 
        AND (wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'epicredvote' ) 
    ORDER BY wp_usermeta.meta_value+0 DESC
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Still getting 'no users found'. If I write it as I did (meta_value_num) it returns users, just in alphabetical order. If I do it your way (pre_user_query) and with meta_value it just returns 'no users found'.

Comment: If you use a non existing `orderby` field, like `meta_value_num`, then you get the default `orderby` field as `login` instead. Did you try `first_name` instead of `epicredvote` ?

Comment: Yeah, still no output using firstname as the meta_key, edited my question to reflect.

Comment: I tested your code, with and without my filter, it worked. I updated the answer with the resulting SQL query. I also tested `first_name`, and it worked as well. Maybe you should try this on a vanilla install? You have to make sure the user meta key **exists** for the users, otherwise you get empty result.

Comment: Well by virtue of the fact I can get the number value on author.php, the meta key definitely exists for users. See my edit from yesterday.

Comment: ok, I read your edits in a way that `epicredvote` were the *post meta* key, not *user meta* key ;-) Where do you use `update_user_meta()` ? You can always check the database table to verify the user meta key exists.

Comment: Ok I can query by first_name. I dumped my database and I'm checking for epicredvote as a key now. Will report back.

Comment: Alright well, I'm silly. Although I can get the total number of 'points' each user has recieved on their author.php page, apparently it's not a user meta key. Urgh. Still possible to query users based on the number of votes they've received on their posts or will I need to learn how to create a user some sort of table/meta key or whatever?

Comment: ok, that explains it. You could maintain the user meta `epicredvote`, for each user, with something like `update_user_meta( 123, 'epicredvote', 20 );` as an example. Then you can use the above code snippet to order the users by `epicredvote`.

Comment: Reading about update_user_meta just now. Trying to get my head around the logic for this. So it's creating a new row in the database (sorry, not particularly knowledgeable about DB's and their structures etc), will it automatically know the meta_key count for each user?

Comment: It will work just as post meta (key/value store). For large user base, you might want to generate this via wp-cron for example and not use the user meta table to store the epicredvote for each user. Just loop over all users, calculate epicredvote for each one, sort the resulting array, filter it, and store the resulting html code in an option or external file. I think there are many examples, on this site or Stack Overflow, how you could do it, i.e. how to run and cache the result from a heavy script. But I guess that's out of the scope of this current question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Before your query:

```
    $wp_user_query = new WP_User_Query($query);
```

You can modify the SQL query string by using the 'pre_user_query' hook.

This hook allows you to modify the sql query that has been prepared but not yet sent to db.

Create a function to replace the ORDER BY section of the sql. Add in 'ORDER BY CAST' and 'as DECIMAL' like below to force the returned result to be numeric before it is sorted.

```
    add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'score_sort_pre_user_query' );

    function score_sort_pre_user_query( $query )
    {
        remove_action( current_action(), __FUNCTION__ );

        $query->query_orderby = str_replace( 
            'ORDER BY wp_usermeta.meta_value', 
            'ORDER BY CAST(wp_usermeta.meta_value as DECIMAL)', 
            $query->query_orderby 
        );
    }
```