# User list order by user meta

Tags: users, user-meta, order

i have created user vote that can vote users or author of posts. so for example have 4 users which looks:

1. user --- ID=1 --- META KEY='_thumbs_rating_up' --- META VALUE='13'
2. user --- ID=2 --- META KEY='_thumbs_rating_up' --- META VALUE='17'
3. user --- ID=3 --- META KEY='_thumbs_rating_up' --- META VALUE='8'
4. user --- ID=4 --- META KEY='_thumbs_rating_up' --- META VALUE='241'

So i must order these users by user meta key and meta value from heighest to lowwer. So i have these code now but order is not correct:

```
<?php
$args = array( 
'role' => 'Seller',
'meta_key' => '_thumbs_rating_up',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
);

// The Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// User Loop
if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {

        echo '<p>' . get_avatar( $user->ID, 32 ) . '</p>';
        echo '<p>' . get_user_meta($user->ID, '_thumbs_rating_up', true). '</p>';
        echo '<p>' . $user->display_name . '</p>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No users found.';
}
?>
```

what i do wrong or simply can not order my custom meta key??????

- i find the post here which is similar but i dont know how can i help with these answers: [Sort users by meta_value_num](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149342/sort-users-by-meta-value-num)

Answer (score 0):

The QA that you have linked to is related but not needed here.

`meta_value_num` is still not part of the user_query core and so, your meta_value_num parameter has no effect on the query.

Just use `meta_value` [as described on codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) and you'll get what you want.

Comment: I also try with only meta_value and not work...

Comment: ok now work i dont write  meta_value ...sory and thnx for help

Answer (score 0):

you can missing the ORDER = DESC. Try this

```
<?php 
$args = array( 
'role' => 'Seller',
'meta_key' => '_thumbs_rating_up',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'DESC'
);
```